# How can I update the plot with React plotly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, plotly

I have the following Snippet to draw a plot with plotly in React:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div id="plot_div">
                <Plot
                    data={[
                        {
                            x: this.x,
                            y: this.y,
                            type: 'scatter',
                            mode: 'markers',
                            marker: {color: this.colors},
                            text: this.labels
                        }
                    ]}
                    layout={{width: 500, height: 500,
                    }}
                    config={{scrollZoom: false, editable: false, displayModeBar: false}}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

When `this.colors` changes, I want the plot to be redrawn. But this does not happen automatically. How can I force the component to update the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to add the `datarevision` property to `layout`, which one can update via a state variable, i.e.

```
layout={{width: 500, height: 500, datarevision: this.state.revise}}
```

Comment: datarevision – If provided, a changed value tells Plotly.react that one or more data arrays has changed. This way you can modify arrays in-place rather than making a complete new copy for an incremental change. If NOT provided, Plotly.react assumes that data arrays are being treated as immutable, thus any data array with a different identity from its predecessor contains new data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use useEffect() hook from react:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Plotly.react('plot_div', [data], layout);
}, [data])
```

Comment: I posted the comment and then realized that you're using react-plotly.js it seems. then, probably, my advise is not the best :)

Comment: accordingly to the [documentation](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js#refreshing-the-plot): 
"In short, this means that simply adding data points to a trace in data or changing a value in layout will not cause a plot to update unless this is done immutably via something like [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) if performance considerations permit it, or unless revision and/or layout.datarevision are used to force a rerender."